Adding extra PAM modules on yocto
I'm new to yocto, I'm trying to add the 'pwquality' pam module to the image but I'm struggling with it, initially I have added this line to the local.conf file:

DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " pam"

which added pam and some modules but the module that i want which is 'pwquality' was not part of the installed modules, any idea how to add it?
 
